# How to prevent Forms from creating new entry even after setting the primary key

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have form that collects information from User and stores the information on a fusion sheet.
I have set the User ID as primary key, However the user is able to make multiple entries in the form with the same User ID.

How can i set the primary key so that there is no duplicates records in the fusion sheet.

Comment: Can you expand your question a table example and some mock data that you are collecting? AFAIK you can't prevent a user from writing whatever they want in the fusion sheet

Comment: thanks @fmsf, you are correct, i checked myself there is no way to restrict fusion sheet user to writing anything